# Libgdx sprite not scalling with viewport

Tags: libgdx, sprite, projection, spritebatch

I have a stretch viewport that I update everytime the screen is rezised with:

```
viewport.update(x, y, true);
```

I drew a background with photoshop and then i removed the objects and put those in a separate file, so what i mean by this is that the objects are in the correct size from origin since i separated them from the original background and texturepacked them.

What i find is that if i draw this objects (using Sprite) i have to set the scale of each sprite to 2.25 otherwise the sprites would be smaller and I dont know what i am doing wrong since im using a single camera/viewport, a single batch and calling batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined).

What i am doing wrong?

This is how i created the viewport and camera:

```
public static Dimension virtualResolution = VirtualResolution.RES_768x432.resolution;
public static Dimension screenResolution = new Dimension(1920, 1080); 

camera = new OrthographicCamera();
camera.setToOrtho(false, GameSettings.virtualResolution.getWidth(), GameSettings.virtualResolution.getHeight());
camera.update();

viewport = new StretchViewport(GameSettings.screenResolution.getWidth(), GameSettings.screenResolution.getHeight(), camera);
viewport.apply();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using Cameras and Viewports correctly.

Cameras have their own "view width" and "view height" which you actually specify in the `setToOrtho` method. However you don't need to set such things to a camera when you are using a Viewport.

Instead you give these size parameters to the Viewport constructor along with an Orthographic camera.

```
gamecam = new OrthographicCamera();
gamePort = new StretchViewport(V_WIDTH, V_HEIGHT, gamecam);
gamePort.apply();
gamecam.position.set(new Vector3(100, 100, 0));
```

In your game you will always work with the camera unless the screen is resized.

If the screen is resized is the code will look like this.

```
@Override public void resize(int width, int height) {
    gamePort.update(width, height); // The third boolean parameter
                                    // centers the camera
}
```

In your question you used two sizes, one based off of the screen resolution, the other a virtual width and height. You will only use one and this gets passed to the Viewport.

This should now correctly scale your sprites!

I hope this answer helped! If you have any more questions please feel free to comment below!